# Why does 뵙겠습니다 have 겠 in it?

Tags: grammar

If the phrase 처음 뵙겠습니다 literally means “this is the first time I’m seeing you”, why does it have 겠 in it? I thought 겠 expressed future intention. I’m asking because I like to understand the literal meanings of everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meanings of the -겠- infix are not limited to simple "future" (and actually, it is only one of several future-based verb structures).

On this StackExchange, the question has arisen with [알겠습니다](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/471/why-is-the-%EA%B2%A0-particle-used-in-%EC%95%8C%EA%B2%A0%EC%8A%B5%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4) already.

The meaning of -겠- in the phrase 처음 뵙겠습니다 is likely to be categorised into the third meaning there, that of *"possibility / capability"*.

TTMIK has a lesson on it, where [these various meanings](https://talktomeinkorean.com/lessons/l6l16) are explored.

These meanings are all related. Hence linguists have dubbed it: "definite future", "deductive-reasoning", "assertive", "conjectural", "presumptive", "intentional", "prospective". Those descriptions *may* help, but what you really want is greater exposure to where -겠- is used in real life.